# ML model running on test server but not on production server

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, facebook-prophet

My prophet model is running on test server. But the same model take error in production server. I used Python 3.7.6 and prophet libray is 0.6 version. Other libraries are the same version. But I take an this error in production.

```
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007f5425728740 (most recent call first):
  File "/vhosting/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexers.py", line 211 in maybe_convert_indices
  File "/vhosting/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1386 in take
  File "/vhosting/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4937 in sort_values
  File "/vhosting/GBYATANOMALY/scripts/GBYATANOMALY.py", line 109 in pre_processing
  File "/vhosting/GBYATANOMALY/scripts/GBYATANOMALY.py", line 318 in <module>
```

There is no problem in data. It is running with production data on development server.

pre_processing function is below.

```
def pre_processing(df_upd):
df_notnull = df_upd

df_notnull['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df_notnull['TIME_X'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
df_dt = df_notnull[['TIME', 'DIMENSION', 'TARGET']]
df_dt['TARGET'] = df_dt['TARGET'].astype('float32')
df_dt.sort_values(by='TIME', ascending=True, inplace=True)
df_dt = df_dt[df_dt['TARGET'] == df_dt.groupby(['TIME', 'DIMENSION'])['TARGET'].transform(max)]

return df_dt
```

Comment: Check packages install on both servers including versions

Comment: Yes, I controlled all packages on both servers, are the same

Comment: Which line generated the error?

Comment: in sort_values line     File "/vhosting/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4937 in sort_values

Comment: This one?: df_dt.sort_values(by='TIME', ascending=True, inplace=True)

Comment: yes, in there. But is running on development server, all packages version are the same. But it is not running on production

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a problem in installation. I would try uninstalling and installing Pandas.

If this does not help, do the same for python